# Create a trigger in sql server after a column is update to specified value

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

i need to create a trigger that do this action:

If the column "idStatoTicket" is update to the value "3" i've to set another column ("dataChiusura") to the current timestamp.

I've tryed this

```
CREATE TRIGGER Customer_UPDATE
       ON TICKET
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

       DECLARE @dataChiusura datetime  

       IF UPDATE(idStatoTicket = 3)
       BEGIN
              SET @dataChiusura = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
       END

       INSERT INTO TICKET(dataChiusura)
       VALUES(@dataChiusura)
END
```

Some Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the `INSERTED` to your original table to be able to change the value to what you want it to be.

Here is a working example for you:

```
Drop Table MyTable
GO
Create Table MyTable 
(
Id Int Identity (1, 1),
Value VarChar (100),
idStatoTicket Int,
DataChiusura DateTime
)
GO
Insert Into MyTable Values ('Test 1', 1, GetDate())
Insert Into MyTable Values ('Test 2', 3, GetDate()-1)
Select * From MyTable
GO
Create Trigger MyTable_Update ON MyTable FOR Update
as
Begin
    Update T
    Set DataChiusura = GetDate()
    From  MyTable T 
    Inner Join Inserted i
        On T.Id = i.id
        And i.idStatoTicket = 3
End
GO
Update MyTable Set Value = 'Test 22' Where Value = 'Test 2'
Select * From MyTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the INSERTED data set to check for the value. Please try something like that:

```
if exists (
    select * from INSERTED where idStatoTicket = 3
) 
begin
  SET @dataChiusura = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but you seem to do separate insert not related to the row being updated and you probably end up with an empty row with just   dataChiusura set ..